# How to add IsAuthenticated decorator only for POST method, but GET without Authentication?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

How to add @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated]) to chek only for POST method IsAuthenticated?

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def products_list(request):
    """
    List of all Products, or create a new Products.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        products = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

P.S. Not split into two functions, i need a single view.

Answer (score 0):

You can override IsAuthenticated permission like this:

```
class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == "GET":
           return True
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
```

Answer (score -1):

`IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` solved my problem.

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly])
```

See: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly